# Lucene adds string with a space to index as two separate values

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

What I'm trying to do is too add a value to index as follows:

```
doc.Add(new Field("field_name", value, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
```

The value is `"Cell phones"`, so what it actually does is adding of two seperate values to index `"Cell"` and `"phones". How to make it to add one: "Cell phones"?

Comment: `Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED`...

Answer (score 0):

As @femtoRgon suggests NOT_ANALYZED is a good option.

But you must also take care with how the query is constructed. The analysis method must be compatible between indexing and querying.

If you use QueryParser you can use something like KeywordAnalyzer. Also look at PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper so you use different methods for different fields.

It is also sensible to add multiple fields for the same value but analyzed in different ways for different styles of query